# App crashes when dismissing view controller

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, swift3

I've a simple ViewController that displays my current location coordinates.

Everything is working properly, but when I dismiss the ViewController, the app crashes without any specific error log.

The class code goes like this:

```
import UIKit

class LocationViewController:   UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {



// General objects
@IBOutlet var closeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var latitudeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var longitudeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var infoButton: UIButton!


// Global variables
var location: CLLocationManager? = CLLocationManager()
var geocoder = CLGeocoder();
var placemark = CLPlacemark();
var hasPin: Bool = false;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
    location?.requestAlwaysAuthorization();

    // For use in foreground
    location?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();

    getCurrentLocation();
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func closeButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        print("dismissing locationViewController");
        self.location = nil;
    });
}



@IBAction func infoButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    // TODO
}


// MARK: - General functions
func getCurrentLocation() -> Void {
    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
        location?.delegate = self;
        location?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        location?.startUpdatingLocation();
    }
}





// MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("ERROR = \(error)");
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    // Gets the user coordinates
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate;
    USER_LATITUDE = locValue.latitude;
    USER_LONGITUDE = locValue.longitude;

    longitudeLabel.text = "\(USER_LONGITUDE)";
    latitudeLabel.text = "\(USER_LATITUDE)";

    location?.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Does anyone have any clue why this happens?

No error log is prompted that's what makes me even more confused.

First I thought I had to set the location variable to be optional and then set it to nil when I dismiss the VC but the crash is still happening.

Crashlytics says that the App crashes inside the LocationViewController line 0 , which is in fact weird.

I call this ViewController, from a button click inside another VC like this:

```
@IBAction func locationButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "locationVC");
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

I'm using Swift3 with the latest Xcode Beta Version on iOS 10.

- Thanks

Comment: nothing appears, only this - **(lldb)** in blue color; I've also found this log in crashlytics - **38 libdispatch.dylib              0x1939cc5b8 (Missing)**

Comment: And it stops inside my AppDelegate, line 15 which is `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {`

Comment: It's not. The crash was happening, and then I set up Crashlytics to help me find out the crash log. It's 100% not Crashlytics, guaranteed

Comment: I'm really thinking there's something up with the CLLocationManager. I've other VC called the same way and dismissed and they work properly, but this one crashes and it's the only one using CLLocationManager :(

Comment: At the `(lldb)` prompt, type `thread back` and hit Return and tell me what you see.

Comment: Also try deleting `self.location = nil` and see if that cures the crash.

Comment: it shows this  -  thread #1: tid = 0x33d61, 0x000000019c9d64a4 CoreLocation`___lldb_unnamed_symbol1457$$CoreLocation + 44, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)

Comment: Enable exception breakpoint in breakpoint's panel - it's really useful

Comment: I really would suggest not using an Optional for your location manager and not setting the location manager to `nil`. I've never seen that before and it seems nutty to me.

Comment: I made it because i thought the locations was still in use when I dismiss the VC, so I've set it to Optional to force release it with nil. But I've saw that's not the case

Comment: thread backtrace [link](https://ghostbin.com/paste/mxvz4)

Comment: I would suggest you to set CLLocationManager's delegate to nil before calling self.dismiss method.

Comment: just did and still crashes. I googled the EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8) but found out vague stuff

Comment: Found out that the EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8) error refers to when you're trying to access some object that has been deallocated already.

Comment: "the EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8) error refers to when you're trying to access some object that has been deallocated already" Yes, we all know that. What we've been trying to suggest is what that object might be. We're thinking it might be you, the view controller. That's why azimov suggested you nilify the location manager's delegate, and why I suggested that you turn off updating, before you go out of existence - because those things involve the delegate.

Comment: @matt indeed! I've made those changes but it keeps crashing. The thing is that it only happens when using the LocationManager, that's why I'm focusing on that. I'll try some other small changes to get close to the problem. It's weird but kinda interesting what it's causing the crash. Thank you for the given help :)

Comment: Any chance you can reduce this project to something minimal and post it on github? I'd be glad to take a look at it for you.

Comment: @matt somehow the issue is solved. I deleted the ViewController xib, deleted the class, created a new one from scratch only with the CLLocationManagerDelegate, without the optional variable and the crash gone away. Still don't know what caused the crash. I've also updated from beta 5 to Xcode 8 beta 6 - don't know if it had something to do with it.

Comment: @matt maybe I could have a object bi-directional pointing to something that I missed completely, but the fact that a specific error log didn't showed up was intriguing. But after creating a new VC with a new storyboard ID and a new class with a new button to present it the issue gone away. Thank you all for the time spent trying to help. I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
var location: CLLocationManager? = CLLocationManager()
```

With this:

```
let location = CLLocationManager()
```

Change all code as necessary (this is no longer an Optional so there is nothing to unwrap) and delete the line that tries to set it to `nil`.

If you are worried that the location manager might be trying to get your location when you dismiss, then implement `viewWillDisappear` and tell it to stop updating.

Comment: let me try it out

Comment: By the way, you should also fix `manager.location!.coordinate`. You can easily crash there because the `location` can very well be `nil`. _Never_ use an exclamation mark unless you very very sure of your ground.

Comment: Hey, it looks like you have turned on zombies. Try turning them back off...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the privacy entry in Info.plist and also request authorization to use location services. A good overview can be found here: http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/

Comment: I've added it into the info.plist file, but I'll read carefully the given link and see if I'm missing something